# Derivative of function with product.

Tags: calculus

I'm supposed to derive the function $f(x) =(4+6x)\ln|x|$ in my homework set. Following the product rule I end up with the derivative function

$$f'(x)=6\ln|x|+ \frac{4+6x}{x},$$

or alternatively:

$$f'(x)= 2\frac{3x\ln|x|+3x+2}{x}.$$

However, these are apparently not correct. I am wondering of I may be missing some sort of simplification step.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: So we have a WebWork module where i put the answers through and I keep getting back that it is incorrectly solved. Thank you for quick reply though!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your working, although I think it is simpler the following way:

Writing $f(x) = 4\ln |x| + 6x\ln|x|,$ we can differentiate using the product rule to get:

$$f'(x) = \frac 4x + 6\ln|x| + \frac{6x}{x} = \frac 4x + 6\ln|x| + 6.$$

Comment: That does look better! Although I keep getting back that the function is incorrectly differentiated. I'm going to contact my course instructor to see whether there perhaps might be something wrong with the module itself!

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong?

Comment: I think that the function has been correctly derived, but I think that perhaps the program where I type in my answers has an incorrect answer stored or something like that. I have put the function through Wolfram and other sites and I keep getting an answer identical to the one you and I derived. So therefor, the problem most likely doesnt lie with the solution provided.